# How to Add Self-Issued CA Generated by VMWare to Browser's (IE) Trusted CA?

Tags: windows, vmware-server, internet-explorer-8, certificate

I just installed VMware Server 2.x.

The install provides a shortcut to a URL using HTTPS (e.g. https://mybox/something), and the certificate presented by VMWare's internal web server is issued to "mybox" - however the CA is also "mybox".

Thus a certificate error is flagged.

Can anyone remind me where I can find the certificate for "mybox" and add it to my trusted CAs in my browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out.

The certificate that VMware Server 2.x created on my box was in .../Program Files (x86)/VMware/VMwareServer/SSL/rui.crt

When I navigated to Trused Root Certificates in IE8, then used the Import Certificate... button, and selected rui.crt, it imported to the Trusted Root Certificates store.

Of course, it warned me to be sure that I really trust "mybox" before installing it.

Comment: ...nothing like forgetting to check SF, then having an answer show up in google to save the day [couldn't remember how to get the certificate installed to enable VMware server control panel to run without security warnings]